# logistic regression with slack

Tags: logistic, bayesian

I have a Bayesian model that tries to predict a binary variable that I am modelling as logistic regression. The training data have lot of wrong labels*. Therefore, I think I might need to introduce some sort of slack (similar to slack variable that SVM). How can I do this?

If I model logistic regression ignoring errors in training data, is logistic regression robust?

*The logistic regression training-data is sampled from another Bayesian model therefore there is large variance in my Gibbs sampling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logistic regression already has some slack but if you want even more slack you can use a softer link function.  For example, replace the logistic function $\sigma(x)$ with $\sigma(\lambda \tanh(x/\lambda))$ where $\lambda$ controls the amount of slack.  Alternatively, you can have an explicit noise model on the labels, i.e. each label gets flipped with probability $p$.

Comment: Thanks Minka. That's helpful. I think slack in logistic regression is not enough in my case because of lot of mis-labelled data. The side-effect is that  $\sigma(x)$ is limited between .01 to .4. Is there are any other modelling possibility to model the binary variable instead of logistic regression?

Comment: If you don't like my link function above, another robust link function is $1/2 + arctan(x)/\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

If the labels are wrong it might be worth looking at a model for logistic regression in the presence of label noise, [Bootkrajang and Kaban](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~axk/papers_by_yr.htm)   have done some interesting work on this recently (which I suspect is the sort of thing Tom Minka had in mind?).

Comment: Yes, their paper [Label-noise Robust Logistic Regression and its Applications](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~jxb008/papers/ecml2012.pdf) has an explicit label-flipping model as I suggested.